# Bash - modifying WhitelistedBlockedPlugins in plist text file

Tags: macos, bash, replace, plist

I am attempting to automate adding a whitelist of otherwise blocked applications and sites for Safari concerning Java. I am able to export the binary plist and edit it via bash, but I'm stuck on how to search and replace or simply add to the file with particular placement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BookmarksSidebarWidth</key>
    <real>194</real>
        ...
    <key>WhitelistedBlockedPlugins</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>PluginHostname</key>
            <string>www.java.com</string>
            <key>PluginIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.oracle.java.JavaAppletPlugin</string>
            <key>PluginLastVisitedDate</key>
            <date>2013-06-05T17:03:26Z</date>
            <key>PluginName</key>
            <string>Java Applet Plug-in</string>
            <key>PluginPageURL</key>
            <string>http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp</string>
            <key>PluginPolicy</key>
            <string>PluginPolicyBlockWhenInsecure</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    ...
    <key>com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2UsesPageCache</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The

```
<key>WhitelistedBlockedPlugins</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        ....
        ....
    </dict>
</array>
```

is the bit I'd like to search for and replace, or add, if it doesn't exist. If it exists, it is ok to replace everything starting with the `<key>WhitelistedBlockedPlugins</key>` and ending with the closing `</array>` as we'd like to control what is going in there anyway.

If it does not exist, I suppose I can add it just before the final `</dict>` at the end of the file.

This is the logic I've come up with, but I am having a very hard time finding a solution where I can search for, if found replace, if not found add.

I've tried a few things without success after reading similar posts on Stack Overflow. I am willing to use anything native to OSX, including that which comes with XCode/CLI Tools.

Things I've tried:

`echo` into the file works, but I'm not finding out how to do it before the `</dict>` and I'd only want to do that if the `<key>WhitelistedBlockedPlugins</key>` and corresponding array is nowhere to be found. Anyone have any guidance or solution? Thanks

Comment: In bash (in linux) for simple replacing (mostly something in one line) I would use `sed` (sed = (S)tream (ED)itor) but your example seems to me more complicate so I would use `python` script (or other language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tackled the same problem but was able to use defaults to modify the com.apple.Safari.plist.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Get today's date
TODAY=$(/bin/date "+%FT%TZ")

# Determine OS version
osvers=$(sw_vers -productVersion | awk -F. '{print $2}')

# Server1's address
SERVER1=server1.name.here

# Server2's address
SERVER2=server2.name.here

# Get Java plug-in info
JAVA_PLUGIN=`/usr/bin/defaults read "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Info" CFBundleIdentifier`

# Check com.apple.Safari.plist for Server1 address
SERVER1_WHITELIST_CHECK=`/usr/bin/defaults read $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari WhitelistedBlockedPlugins | grep PluginHostname | awk '{print $3}' | grep $SERVER1 | tr -d '";'`

# Check com.apple.Safari.plist for Server2 address
SERVER2_WHITELIST_CHECK=`/usr/bin/defaults read $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari WhitelistedBlockedPlugins | grep PluginHostname | awk '{print $3}' | grep $SERVER2 | tr -d '";'`

if [[ ${osvers} -ge 6 ]]; then
  if [[ -n ${SERVER1_WHITELIST_CHECK} ]]; then

        # Server1 settings are present
    /usr/bin/logger "${SERVER1_WHITELIST_CHECK} is part of the Java whitelist in Safari. Nothing to do here."
    else        
    # Add Server1 to Java whitelist
        /usr/bin/defaults write $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari "WhitelistedBlockedPlugins" -array-add '{"PluginHostname" = "'$SERVER1'"; "PluginIdentifier" = "'$JAVA_PLUGIN'"; "PluginLastVisitedDate" = "'$TODAY'"; "PluginName" = "Java Applet Plug-in"; "PluginPageURL" = "https://'$SERVER1'"; "PluginPolicy" = "PluginPolicyNeverBlock";}'
        /usr/bin/logger "$SERVER1 has been added to the Java whitelist in Safari."
  fi

  if [[ -n ${SERVER2_WHITELIST_CHECK} ]]; then

    # Server2 settings are present
    /usr/bin/logger "${SERVER2_WHITELIST_CHECK} is part of the Java whitelist in Safari. Nothing to do here."
     else       
        # Add Server2 to Java whitelist
    /usr/bin/defaults write $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari "WhitelistedBlockedPlugins" -array-add '{"PluginHostname" = "'$SERVER2'"; "PluginIdentifier" = "'$JAVA_PLUGIN'"; "PluginLastVisitedDate" = "'$TODAY'"; "PluginName" = "Java Applet Plug-in"; "PluginPageURL" = "https://'$SERVER2'"; "PluginPolicy" = "PluginPolicyNeverBlock";}'
        /usr/bin/logger "$SERVER2 has been added to the Java whitelist in Safari."
  fi

fi

exit 0
```

[The code's also available here on my GitHub repo.](https://github.com/rtrouton/rtrouton_scripts/tree/master/rtrouton_scripts/safari_java_whitelist)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, your method would absolutely be preferred! It's funny, I've perused your github in the past and actually recently talked to a colleague located in Toronto and he said he met you at some conference. Great work, and thanks for all the help you've provided me in the past and I'm sure in the future. :D

Comment: The com.apple.Safari.plist for safari 6.1 has a key called ManagedPlugInPolicies. This is different than the WhitelistedBlockedPlugins.

Answer (score 0):

You might just use defaults:

`defaults write ./file.plist WhitelistedBlockedPlugins -array '<dict><key>a</key><string>b</string></dict>'`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but writing defaults just wasn't able to handle the complexity I was trying to achieve or I certainly couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Because this was a case of modifying a `plist` file and using OSX to do so, I found using `Plistbuddy` was my easiest solution. If I needed to find and replace, keep certain sites, or add with certain conditions, I would have ended up using Perl or Python I'm sure....but I had the luxury of just wiping out that entire array and writing in what I wanted.

Below is my solution which I will probably end up creating into a LaunchDaemon or Agent so this occurs per User and on each boot (wiping out non-authorized or approved Java applets and ensures our needed sites are added).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Convert the com.apple.Safari.plist from binary plist to readable text file
plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist > /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist

# Deletes the WhitelistedBlockedPlugins Key and corresponding array, if it exists
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete WhitelistedBlockedPlugins" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist

# Adds the WhitelistedBlockedPlugins Key and array including two whitelisted sites
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins array" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:0 dict" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:0:PluginHostname string 'www.java.com'" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:0:PluginIdentifier string 'com.oracle.java.JavaAppletPlugin'" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:0:PluginLastVisitedDate date 'Wed Jul 10 12:00:00 PST 2013'" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:0:PluginName string 'Java Applet Plug-in'" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:0:PluginPageURL string 'http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp'" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:0:PluginPolicy string 'PluginPolicyNeverBlock'" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:1 dict" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:1:PluginHostname string 'another.siteexample.com'" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:1:PluginIdentifier string 'com.oracle.java.JavaAppletPlugin'" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:1:PluginLastVisitedDate date 'Wed Jul 10 12:05:00 PST 2013'" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:1:PluginName string 'Java Applet Plug-in'" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:1:PluginPageURL string 'http://another.siteexample.com/some/path'" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :WhitelistedBlockedPlugins:1:PluginPolicy string 'PluginPolicyNeverBlock'" /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist

# copy the modified plist back where Safari will then use it and convert it back to binary plist itself
cp /tmp/com.apple.Safari.plist ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
```

Again, for reference, this was a way to automatically add a list of approved sites to Safari. I was inspired to do so after seeing a need to make it easier to add our approved sites on client computers and reading http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/04/18/apple-updates-safari-gives-better-control-over-java-applets/